# Acessar Json multidimensional PHP/Laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel-5

Estou tentando acessar um Json multidimensional via laravel e não estou conseguindo o resultado esperado, preciso acessar fases->jogos->data->2017-05-13 vou postar o código a baixo para encontrar-mos uma solução:

Meu array:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Controller.php

```
public function index(){



    // JSON DOS ARQUIVOS
    $arquivo_json = file_get_contents('http://jsuol.com.br/c/monaco/utils/gestor/commons.js?file=commons.uol.com.br/sistemas/esporte/modalidades/futebol/campeonatos/dados/2017/30/dados.json');
    $dadosJson = json_decode($arquivo_json, true);

    return view('ler', compact('dadosJson'));
}
```

view.php

```
@foreach($dadosJson['fases'] as $equipes)
        @foreach($equipes['jogos'] as $jogos)
            {{ $jogos['nome'] }}
        @endforeach

    @endforeach
```

retorno
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém poderia me dar uma ajuda?

Obrigado!

Comment: Parece estar certo. Talvez tenha algum `data` de `jogos` que não existe. Faça uma condição antes verificando se a chave existe para continuar. `if(array_key_exists('data', $jogos'))`.

Comment: Bom dia @Diego-Souza, fiz da seguinte maneira 
foreach($dadosJson['fases'] as $equipes)
   if(array_key_exists('data', $jogos'))
          foreach($equipes['jogos'] as $jogos)
              {{ $jogos['nome'] }}
          endforeach
         
     endforeach
Mas não conseguiu!

Answer (score 1):

Consegui acessar pelo print_r, mas para visualizar não consigo sempre me retorna o erro:

alterações no controller.php

```
return view('ler')->with('dadosJson', $dadosJson);
```

retorno pelo print_r

```
Array(
[0] => 97071
[1] => 97073)
     1            
                Array(
[0] => 97071
[1] => 97073)
     1           
                Array(
[0] => 97071
[1] => 97073)
```

retorno sem o print_r {{ $equipes['jogos']['data']['2017-05-13'] }}
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguma ajuda?